# animate, несколько действий в разное время

Tags: jquery

Допустим есть движение блока через `.animate()`

```js
let end = $('.way').width() - $('.block').width();
$('.block').animate({
  'left': end
}, 2000, 'linear');
```

```css
.way {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="way">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы когда `end == end - ($('.block').width() * 3)` анимация сменилась, причём резко и без "прерывания" самой анимации.
Допустим, чтобы блок стал `background: green; border-radius: 100%`.

Comment: чем плох `progress`-коллбэк?

Comment: или `step`, мб удобнее будет в данном случае

Comment: @teran, про `progress` не слышал, а со `step` не работал. Спасибо, почитаю про них и попробую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

метод `animate` имеет ряд callback-функций, которые вызываются в процессе анимации. Вам могут быть интересны методы `step` и `progress`.

- `step` вызывается для каждого анимируемого свойства в каждый шаг анимации, и первым параметром будет текущее значение свойства.
- `progress` вызывается одноразово для всех свойств  на каждый шаг, тут вы получите процент завершения анимации.

То есть с использованием `step`, упрощенно это можно сделать как-то так

```js
let end = $('.way').width() - $('.block').width();
let swPos = end - 3*$(".block").width();


$('.block').animate({
              left: end
            }, { 
              duration:  2000,  
              easing : 'linear',
              step: function(n, fx){                 
                 if(n >= swPos) $(this).addClass('block-2')
              }
            });
```

```css
.way {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.block-2 {
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="way">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот это прям то, что нужно! Спасибо)